# How do you add a single parameter of an object with multiple parameters to a string from an arraylist of that object?

Tags: java, eclipse, string, arraylist, tostring

I am trying to rewrite the toString() to print names. I use getNm() from each employee in an arraylist of object employees. Employees have the parameters (pay, nm, hoursWorked, overtimeHours)
I have bolded the code I am focused on.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        workers workerlist = new workers();
        workerlist.setNumberEmployees();
        workerlist.instantiateEmployees();
        System.out.println(workerlist.toString());
    }
}

public class Employees extends workers{
    public double pay;
    public String nm;
    public double hours;
    public double overtime;

    public Employees(double pay, String nm, double hoursWorked, double overtimeHours){
    }

        public double getPay(){
            return pay;
        }

        public void setPay(double pay){
        }

        public String getNm(){
            return nm;
        }

        public void setNm(String nm){
        }

        public double getHours(){
            return hours;
        }

        public void setHours(double hours){
        }

        public double getOvertime(){
            return overtime;
        }

        public void setOvertime(double overtime){
        }

    }

  import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class workers{
    public int employeenumber;
    public String nm;
    ArrayList<Employees> workerList = new ArrayList<Employees>();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void setNumberEmployees(){
        System.out.println("How many employees do you have?");
        employeenumber = input.nextInt();
    }

    public int getNumberEmployees(){
        return employeenumber;
    }

    public void instantiateEmployees(){
        for(int i=1; i<=employeenumber; i++){
            workerList.add(new Employees(0.0, "nm", 0.0, 0.0));
        }
    }


    public String toString(){
        String st = "";
        for(int i=0; i<employeenumber; i++){
            **st += workerList.toString();**
// ".toString() is there to test the setting of parameters, I am interested in replacing this part.
        }

        return st;
    }

}
```

Expected Output [Employee 1's name, Employee 2's name,... Employee n's name]

Comment: What do you mean by "test the setting of parameters"?

Comment: To see if the Object Employee is accepting the instantiation of the variables. Therefore when I run with workerList.toString() it will print [ , , , ,] for each employeenumber @Maljam

Comment: Could you add your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public String toString(){
    String st = "";
    for(int i=0; i < employeenumber; i++)
        st += workerList.get(i).toString();

    return st;
}
```

But this solution is not the best. I suggest you the next one:

```
public String toString(){
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    workerList.stream().map(Employees::toString).forEach(builder::append);

    return builder.toString();
}
```

And, of course, you have to override `toString()` in the `Employees` class. For example,

```
@Override public String toString() {
    return new StringJoiner(", ")
                .add(Double.toString(pay))
                .add(nm)
                .add(Double.toString(hours))
                .add(Double.toString(overtime))
            .toString();
}
```

Comment: Why do you suggest the second solution? Is it more efficient? What does it do that solution one doesn't do?

Comment: @Adamc23, when we talk about string concatenation, usually we use `StringBuilder`/`StringBuffer` (if we work with multithreading) for a better performance.

Comment: @Amamc23, compiler may optimize the first construction to the  second.

Comment: Upon further reading, it seems that `StringBuilder` / `StringBuffer` append already existing strings. Based on this would it be better to create one main `StringBuilder` for all objects in the list, or an individual `StringBuilder` for each object?

Comment: @Adamc23, one for all

Comment: Upon implementation of the second solution. The error is thrown that add(String) is not defined. Is this not done in the `@Override` ? Along with this type `Stream<String>` is not applicable for the argument does this mean we must also override `Stream()` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106345/discussion-between-andrew-tobilko-and-adamc23).

Answer (score 2):

I think below code will give your expected result.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        workers workerlist = new workers();
        workerlist.setNumberEmployees();
        workerlist.instantiateEmployees();
        System.out.println(workerlist.toString()); //call toString to take workerlist
    }
}
```

Override Employees toString method and do not forget update nm parameter in constructor

```
public class Employees extends workers {
    public double pay;
    public String nm;
    public double hours;
    public double overtime;

    public Employees(double pay, String nm, double hoursWorked, double overtimeHours) {
        this.nm = nm; //do not forget set value
    }

    public double getPay() {
        return pay;
    }

    public void setPay(double pay) {
    }

    public String getNm() {
        return nm;
    }

    public void setNm(String nm) {
    }

    public double getHours() {
        return hours;
    }

    public void setHours(double hours) {
    }

    public double getOvertime() {
        return overtime;
    }

    public void setOvertime(double overtime) {
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getNm(); //Employees toString method will return nm
    }

}
```

override toString method and call arraylist's toString method.

```
public class workers {
    public int employeenumber;
    public String nm;
    ArrayList<Employees> workerList = new ArrayList<Employees>();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void setNumberEmployees() {
        System.out.println("How many employees do you have?");
        employeenumber = input.nextInt();
    }

    public int getNumberEmployees() {
        return employeenumber;
    }

    public void instantiateEmployees() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= employeenumber; i++) {
            workerList.add(new Employees(0.0, "nm", 0.0, 0.0));
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        return workerList.toString(); //no need to iterate on arraylist, Arraylist.toString method will call each Employees toString method.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yusuf K. and Andrew Tobilko have answered your question correctly. Just to give you some hints to improve your classes a bit:

- Why do you call **Employees** eventhough your class can represent a single employee; so I would call it **Employee** instead.
- Why do you define the **nm** field twice? It is declared in **Workers** class from which the **Employees** class is derived.
- **setNumberEmployees()** method does not comply with JavaBeans convention; it must be declared as

  ```
  public void setNumberEmployees(final String noEmployees) {
      employeenumber = noEmployees;
  }
  ```

  And the call to **setNumberEmployees()** should be done in the **main()** method as

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args){
      workers workerlist = new workers();
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      workerlist.setNumberEmployees(input.nextInt());
      workerlist.instantiateEmployees();
      System.out.println(workerlist.toString());
  }
  ```
- And lastly, you are speaking about **parameter(s)**. They are actually called ***fields*** or ***instance variable(s)***.

Comment: I will definitely look into this you really have listed good points. This is what I like to call my scrap program though. I tend to make a sloppy version, and then once everything works and I see if it's efficient, doesn't have errors or skip over things then I like to make a new one a final product if you may. But I will definitely look over these as some of the main points to go over. Sometimes a program really just requires a whole new writing and this might be one of them.

Comment: @ujulu My only argument for you is this. Even in the client the error's will often state parameters of constructors. I.E. If i try and call an empty constructor `Employee A = new Employee();` the error and solution `Change constructor "Employee(double, string, double, double)": remove parameters double, string, double, double` will be given by Eclipse. So how am I wrong by calling these parameters? Wouldn't an instance variable be something as `private String nm;`  and field would be something as simple as `private final int x = 0;` ? correct me if I'm wrong please.

Comment: For me, using the term _parameter_ for constructors and methods is correct. And there is no difference between _instance variable_ and _field_;  ex.: in **public Employee(final String name) {}** (which is supposed to be a constructor) **name** is called **formal parameter** or you just call it **parameter** of the constructor; but when you declare a variable at class level it is **instance variable or field** unless that variable declaration contains the keyword **static** in which case it is called **class variable or static variable**.